# Firebase dynamic link not opening app iOS 14

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am attempting to create dynamic links to work as part of a referral system for my app. I believe I am successfully creating the links, however whenever I click on one from my notes app while running my app (which I am told should just open the app) I am directed to a Safari page then the App Store. This leads me to beleive the dynamic like for whatever reason isn't being handled at all by my app.

I am using a custom domain URI prefix, specifically https://mywebsite.com/invite and here is the complete code for creating my dynamic link

```
            guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
            let link = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/invite/?invitedby=\(uid)")
            let referralLink = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link!, domainURIPrefix: "https://mywebsite.com/invite")
            
            referralLink?.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "myBundleId")
            referralLink?.iOSParameters?.minimumAppVersion = "1.0"
            referralLink?.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "123456789"
            
            referralLink?.shorten { (shortURL, warnings, error) in
                guard let referURL = shortURL else {
                    Service.showAlert(on: self, style: .alert, title: "Link Error", message: "We were unable to retreive your referral link at this time.")
                    return
                }
                let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [referURL], applicationActivities: nil)
                UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

My code that I took from the Firebase documentation that allegedly is intended to handle the incoming dynamic link is as follows.

```
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        return application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: "")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamicLink, error) in
            if (dynamicLink != nil) && !(error != nil) {
                self.handleDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
            }
        }
        return handled
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            return handleDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
        }
        return false
    }
```

In addition to my code, I have ensured that in my info.plist I have listed "https://mywebsite.com/invite" under FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains keys, I have added my apps bundle as a URL Type, and have added applinks:mywebsite.com to my apps Associated Domains.

I have checked multiple other posts and I'm not quite sure what is going wrong here. If someboyd could shed some light on any potential issues that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating link wrong.

You need to set up:

let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domainURIPrefix: "Firebase short link goes here")

let iOSParams = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "IOS app bundle id goes here")

iOSParams.customScheme = "url scheme" // for ios // forandroid firebase have different property